# To find and replace dashes in specific column

Tags: python, linux, sed, awk

I have a file which has has five columns.

File 1 looks like:

```
1111    1111    exm-IND1-200449980  I   I

1111    1111    exm-IND1-201453487  I   -

1111    1111    exm-IND1-85310248   I   I

1111    1111    exm-IND10-102817747 D   D

1111    1111    exm-IND10-18329639  -   D

1111    1111    exm-IND10-27476467  I   I

1111    1111    exm-IND10-27727540  D   -
```

I would like to get rid of `-` but only in columns 4 and 5, and replace `-` with `0` in these instances. I have been using the following line of code:

```
sed '/^\([^\t]*\t[^\t]*\t[^\t]*\)\t-\t-\(.*\)/ s//\1\t0\t\2/' file1 > newfile
```

to address the problem, but feel this is somewhat rather clunky. Does anyone have a more concise suggestion to this problem? As I will be encountering it a lot.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I definitely think that `awk` would be more suited for this ...

Comment: If you have a file with 5 columns, where did the 6th column come from?

Comment: Columns 4 and 5, I apologise. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Awk is a better choice here:

`awk '{sub("-","0",$4); sub("-","0",$5); print}'`

(updated to reflect your updated question)

Answer (score 3):

### GNU sed

```
sed -r ':k;s/-(\s*\S*)$/0\1/g;tk' file
```

..output:

```
1111    1111    exm-IND1-200449980  I   I
1111    1111    exm-IND1-201453487  I   0
1111    1111    exm-IND1-85310248   I   I
1111    1111    exm-IND10-102817747 D   D
1111    1111    exm-IND10-18329639  0   D
1111    1111    exm-IND10-27476467  I   I
1111    1111    exm-IND10-27727540  D   0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{gsub(/-/,"0",$4);gsub(/-/,"0",$5)}1' test.in | column -t
```

`column` is to keep the nice formatting, you can drop it if you don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want:

```
$ awk '$4=="-"{$4=0}$5=="-"{$5=0}{$1=$1}1' OFS='\t'  file
1111    1111    exm-IND1-200449980      I       I

1111    1111    exm-IND1-201453487      I       0

1111    1111    exm-IND1-85310248       I       I

1111    1111    exm-IND10-102817747     D       D

1111    1111    exm-IND10-18329639      0       D

1111    1111    exm-IND10-27476467      I       I

1111    1111    exm-IND10-27727540      D       0
```

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`

```
awk '$4=="-"{$4=0}$5=="-"{$5=0}1' inputFile
```

Comment: This will replace `I` with a 0 in the fourth column on the second line for instance and you're not handling the field separation on output.

Answer (score -1):

In Python you could do the following:

```
file1 = [line.strip().split() for line in open('file1')]
for line in file1:
    line[2] = line[2].replace('-','')
print file1
```